# Minimal words of length n

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let W be a finite word on a two symbol alphabet {0,1}; let us say that W is maximal if it is the last item in the list of all its cyclic permutation (ordered lexicographically).

So, for instance:
{0,1}         are the maximal words of length 1;
{00, 10, 11}  are the maximal words of length 2;
{000, 100, 110, 111}    are the maximal words of length 3;
{0000, 1000, 1010, 1100, 1110, 1111} are the maximal words of length 4;
{00000, 10000, 10100, 11000, 11010, 11100, 11110, 11111} are the maximal words of length 5; ...
und so weiter.

Let 
k(n):= number of maximal words of length n

Is there some formula for k(n)?

Comment: Isn't this just asking for the number of equivalence classes under cyclic permutations? These are called necklaces (or possibly bracelets, I can never remember the difference) and are well studied.

See http://oeis.org/A000031

Comment: By definition, every cyclic conjugacy class of words of length n contains a unique maximal word. So this problem can be restated as: how many orbits are there for the action of the cyclic group of order n on the words of length n over alphabet {0,1} by cyclic rotations.

Comment: @Gordon A necklaces is the equivalence class of a word under cyclic permutation, a bracelet is the equivalence class of a word under cyclic permutation and reflection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For aperiodic (sometimes also called, full period) strings, the term you are looking for is Lyndon words. These are the (unique lexicographically-least) representative of a full-period necklace (as stated in the comments, a necklace is the equivalence class under cyclic rotation). The number $k(n)$ you ask for is exactly the number of necklaces, and again, as stated in the comments, it is given by
$k(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)2^{n/d}$. You can check out a proof for this in S.W.Golomb's book "Shift Register Sequences" (in the 1967 edition, start looking at around page 171 and look for the cycles of $PCR_n$).

Comment: Thanks to everybody!

As a matter of fact, I had checked if the first few items of the sequence were already listed in the "Encyclopedia of integer sequences", but -alas!- I did not find the right answer because of a mistake in the count of 8-letters "maximal" words :-( 

I hope this will not affect my reputation ;-)

Answer (score 6):

please see wikipedia :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)

It represents a structure with n circularly connected beads of up to k different colors or numbers.

Comment: Thanks!

Beware: there is a flaw in your link, due to the fact that the final ")" is missing in the url. 